# Google Sign In Not working when i upload it on Play Store

Tags: android

I have uploaded [my app on play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttb.thetechnicalboy.routerloginsupport).

I have tested my release version before uploading it to play store and it's working fine. 
But when I download the app from above link, google login is not Working.

Comment: What is the bug or error. And post the code where append.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you configure your project on google console by adding SHA key ?

Comment: Yes -Ahsan Malik , I have configure it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Google Play app signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) then your app is signed with a different key when downloaded from Google Play than the build you uploaded.

As it says in the "tips and best practices" section on that page:

> If you want to test the APK signed with the upload key, you will need to register your upload key with any service or API that uses your app's signature for authentication (like the Google Maps API or Facebook SDK). If you're using any Google API, you may want to register the upload certificate in the Google Cloud Console for your app.

Also look at "Step 4" for new apps:

> If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.
>
> To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
>
>    2. Select an app.
>    3. On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
>    4. From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires.